# XSLT copy value from 1 node to another in xml

Tags: xslt

I am creating a xml file using XSLT.
Now in the newly created XML file I m getting the following structure

```
<node1 id=n1>
  <node2 id = n2>
    <node4>Value1</node4>
  </node2>

  <node3 id= n3>
    <node5></node5>
  </node3>
</node1>
```

Now the issue is that I need to copy the value of `<node4>` i.e. "Value1" to `<node5>`

I mean `<node5>Value1</node5>` like this.
Can any one let me know how to achieve this in XSLT?

EDIT: 
Value1 is being generated in a loop that is being applied in XSLT on the xml. 
The main question is just how to copy value from 1 node say  in this case to a new node being created through XSLT
for node 5 I'll be using something like

```
<node5>
  <xsl:text>
    <xsl: select="node1/node2/node4"/>
  </xsl:text>
</node5>
```

Comment: Can you show us your input XML and the XSLT you are using to generate to generate your current output? Thanks!

Comment: Your XSLT code does not make any sense. Please post syntactically valid code samples and a little more context.

Comment: You can't directly make a copy of a value that has been output. You could, perhaps, store the value in a variable before it is output, and then output it multiple places. We would really need to see your XML and current XSLT to determine the best approach though. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

This:

```
<node5>
  <xsl:value-of select="/node1/node2/node4"/>
</node5>
```

sets the content of `node5` in the output XML to the value contained in `node4` in the input XML.

Comment: well, node4 is not in input xml.. its in output xml

Comment: @Gautam: OK - where does `node4` get its value from?